# Java if statement is skipped

Tags: java

In the following Java code, the if statement conditional does not evaluate to true and its block is skipped.

```
public void options(String input)
{
    if(input == "x")
        System.exit(0);
}
```

Input has the right value, so why is the System.exit(0) skipped?

Comment: Does it skip the if statement or evaluates the condition to false and skips System.exit(0); ?

Comment: I'm just gonna vote for every answer. We've all basically said the same thing :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a classic. Don't use "==" for comparing Strings, use String.equals().

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer has got the only votes at the time I'm adding this comment, when it doesn't provide any explanation of *why* `==` doesn't work.

Comment: I agree with that, actually. I should have explained more.

Comment: Votes on answers to trivial questions have no meaning

Answer (score 13):

You're comparing two string references for *identity*, not whether they refer to *equal* strings. It's not *skipping* the `if` statement - it's evaluating the condition, and finding that it's false, so it's not going into the body. Try this:

```
if (input.equals("x"))
```

Or if `input` might be null and you don't want that to cause an exception:

```
if ("x".equals(input))
```

This isn't just true of strings - whenever you have `==`, it will compare the values of the two expressions... and if those values are references, it simply compares whether those two references are equal, i.e. whether they refer to the same object. `equals`, on the other hand, is applied polymorphically - so the object it's called on can determine what constitutes equality for that class.

As another example:

```
Integer x = new Integer(1000);
Integer y = new Integer(1000);

System.out.println(x == y); // false
System.out.println(x.equals(y)); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
"x".equals(input)
```

`==` tests whether they refer to the same object not the content of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use `==` for comparing strings, use `equals`.

```
if(input.equals("x"))
    System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `"X".equals(input)`. For String comparison use equals method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.equals()`, not `==`.

Using `==` will *always* fail: Unlike javascript, in java `==` tests if the two operands are the *same exact object*, which they aren't (one is a String constant, the other was user input)

`.equals()` test if the two objects "have the same value" (class-dependant implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Use == for comparing primitives and object references.

equals for content comparisons(provided it is implemented). String has the equals implemented for content comparison and you should use that.